# how to put rails ActiveStorage attachment in a Prawn pdf?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, prawn, rails-activestorage

I have been using Prawn for years.  Things have changed a little bit now that I have switched over to ActiveStorage.  I'm having trouble using url_for or rails_blob_path in a Prawn::Document.  I thought I would post here and see if anyone has some insight on how to imbed an image in a Prawn::Document using rails ActiveStorage.

I am trying the approach of passing the path in as a parameter when calling the Pdf from a controller...like follows:

```
pdf = IdBadge.new(@user, avatar_path: url_for(@user.avatar))
send_data pdf.render, filename: 'IDBadge.pdf', type: 'application/pdf'
```

then in the prawn document I set

```
@avatar_path = options[:avatar_path]
```

and, then from a method in the pdf I call

```
image(open(@avatar_path), fit: [100, 100], position: :center)
```

I have gotten a few errors trying to work this out...currently the page is timing out at 40000ms preventing me from seeing other underlying errors.

Has anyone imbedded an ActiveStorage image in a Prawn::Document, yet?

Comment: The docs say there is a redirect that happens after you call `@user.avatar`, maybe this is the result of your timeout issue. No idea if this would work, but what if you tried the download link syntax: `rails_blob_path(user.avatar)`?

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this today until I stumbled across this github issue. https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn/issues/1111. Inside your `generate` or `render` method you just put:

```
pdf.image StringIO.open(@model.attachment.download)
```

if you put the generation method in the model it would just be

```
pdf.image StringIO.open(attachment.download)
```

Comment: This is the approach I used, too.  Downloading a variation seems to pull in the original full size file.  Have you done anything like?:  pdf.image StringIO.open(attachment..variant(resize: [250,250]).processed.blob.download)

Answer (score 0):

getting the url would look like this:

```
user.avatar.variant(resize: "100x100").service_url
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me in Rails 5.2.2. It gives me an error: `Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true`. I've tried to set the `host` and `only_path` parameters everywhere I could (in the config files etc.) but that didn't change anything.

Comment: I seem to remember seeing something similar...but, it has been awhile since I worked on this.  I just reviewed my code and see that I am successfully using user.avatar.variant(resize: "100x100").service_url.  I'll repost if I remember anything related to solving your comment.

Comment: That would be great, thanks! I wonder if you've used any of the [hacks described here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/32500)?